# Group csv string by Year

Tags: python, parsing, csv, datetime, pandas

I need to get data with 2014 and 2015 year.
How can I do it If I have a file with strings like (there are 499 thousands)

```
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"e1.ru",2014-09-30 18:14:58,57,4
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"e1.ru",2014-09-30 20:11:15,1884,90
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"e1.ru",2014-10-04 09:44:21,1146,6
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"avito.ru",2014-09-29 21:01:29,48,3
```

I tried to convert date format `d = datetime.strptime('used_at', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`, but I have an error: time data 'used_at' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'.

And I tried `df.groupby(df['date_col'].dt.year)`
but have an error Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
I read csv `infile = pd.read_csv("avito_trend.csv")`

Comment: You can just parse that as a datetime using `read_csv` so `read_csv(file_path, parse_dates=[2])` then you can do `df.groupby(df['date_col'].dt.year)`

Comment: It doesn't work. I have an error: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Can you edit your post with more sample data and code that produces that error, thanks

Comment: Can you also post an example of the data that you are looking to get out, e.g. do you want the entire row where the date is 2014/15?

Comment: I have edited my question. I want to group data to 2014 and 2015, because I should build graph with 2014 and 2015

Comment: What is header of csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select rows with years `2014` and `2015` by [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"e1.ru",2013-09-30 18:14:58,57,4
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"e1.ru",2014-09-30 20:11:15,1884,90
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"e1.ru",2015-10-04 09:44:21,1146,6
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"avito.ru",2016-09-29 21:01:29,48,3"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), #after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
                 header=None, #no header
                 parse_dates=[2], #parse 3rd column to datetime
                 names=['a', 'url', 'used_at', 'b', 'c']) #set columns names

print df
                                  a       url             used_at     b   c
0  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a     e1.ru 2013-09-30 18:14:58    57   4
1  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a     e1.ru 2014-09-30 20:11:15  1884  90
2  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a     e1.ru 2015-10-04 09:44:21  1146   6
3  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a  avito.ru 2016-09-29 21:01:29    48   3

#create boolean mask, which rows contain years 2014 or 2015
print df['used_at'].dt.year.isin([2014,2015])
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: used_at, dtype: bool

#filter dataframe by mask
print df[ df['used_at'].dt.year.isin([2014,2015])]
                                  a    url             used_at     b   c
1  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a  e1.ru 2014-09-30 20:11:15  1884  90
2  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a  e1.ru 2015-10-04 09:44:21  1146   6
```

Edit:

Columns names are in `csv` as `header`, so you can omit them:

```
import pandas as pd

infile = pd.read_csv("avito_trend.csv", 
                      parse_dates=[2])

print infile

print infile[ infile['used_at'].dt.year.isin([2014,2015])]
```

Comment: When I `infile = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("avito_trend.csv"),
                     header=None,
                     parse_dates=[2],
                     names=['ID', 'address', 'used_at', 'active_seconds', 'pageviews'])`              i get `ID  address used_at  active_seconds  pageviews
0  avito_trend.csv      NaN     NaT             NaN        NaN
Series([], Name: active_seconds, dtype: float64)`

Comment: You can try `infile = pd.read_csv("avito_trend.csv", header=None, parse_dates=[2], names=['ID', 'address', 'used_at', 'active_seconds', 'pageviews'])`, omit `io.StringIO`

Comment: I have an error `TypeError: an integer is required;   KeyError: 'used_at'`

Comment: Is possible that some values in column `used_at` are missing?

Comment: After print `                ID  address used_at  active_seconds  pageviews
0  avito_trend.csv      NaN     NaT             NaN        NaN`

Comment: Can you share your file?

Comment: [file](https://yadi.sk/d/A_9pykgVqJ6Ky) That file. in the upper right corner you can download it

Comment: I have no difference between `print infile` and `print infile[ infile['used_at'].dt.year.isin([2014,2015])]`. In each case data are printed, but I have no sort with year

Comment: I check it and in file are only years `2014` and `2015`.

Comment: I think you understood me wrong. In this file data only 2014 and 2015 year. I need divide my data with it. I think it looks like `infile.groupby('used_at')`. I want to get strings to 2014 year and after 2015. If I want get sum of `"active_seconds"` i print `infile.groupby('address').active_seconds.sum()`. But it sum to all_time. But I need separately 2014 and separately 2015. Do you understand me?

Comment: Yes, I think I understand. I think you need `print infile.groupby(['address', infile['used_at'].dt.year]).active_seconds.sum()`

Comment: Should I import anything? `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: Dont you forget for parameter `parse_dates=[2]` in `read_csv` ?

Comment: Really, I forgot it. Thank you so much. Please, can you explain me about meaning of `parse_dates`, what does it mean? I find that it can accept only True and False, so I don't understand.

Comment: It is very easy - it parse third column - it is column `used_at` (python start count from `0`, so it is [2] column) to datetime. check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#datetime-handling)

Comment: I understand. But If i need to count quantity of users to every site, how can i do it? Because I should quantity of IDs, but it doesn't countable

Comment: What do you need? `print infile.groupby('ID')['address'].count()` ? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry, but I think better is post new question, because I think I dont understand very well, what do you want. But each good question has  3 parts: 1. sample of dataframe, sample of csv (5,6 rows) 2. What is desired output from posted sample. 3. What you try (minimal, with errors, no problem). And then someone give you nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be doing what we ask so here is some code that demonstrates that if you did what I asked it would work:

```
In [11]:
import io
import pandas as pd
t="""4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"e1.ru",2014-09-30 18:14:58,57,4
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"e1.ru",2014-09-30 20:11:15,1884,90
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"e1.ru",2014-10-04 09:44:21,1146,6
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"avito.ru",2014-09-29 21:01:29,48,3"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), header=None, parse_dates=[2])
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 5 columns):
0    4 non-null object
1    4 non-null object
2    4 non-null datetime64[ns]
3    4 non-null int64
4    4 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 192.0+ bytes
```

You can see from the above that the `dtype` for the 3rd column is now `datetime64` you can then use `dt.year` to access the year component and `groupby` on that:

```
In [14]:    
df.groupby(df[2].dt.year).first()

Out[14]:
                                     0      1                   2   3  4
2                                                                       
2014  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a  e1.ru 2014-09-30 18:14:58  57  4
```

You can optionally filter or mask using this attribute:

```
In [15]:
df[2].dt.year

Out[15]:
0    2014
1    2014
2    2014
3    2014
Name: 2, dtype: int64
```

you can compare the above to a scalar value or test for membership using `isin` e.t.c.

What you tried:

```
datetime.strptime('used_at', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

is meaningless `strptime` accepts a datetime string, you probably wanted to pass the column:

```
datetime.strptime(df['used_at'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

but that will fail as `strptime` accepts scalar values, not a pandas series.

if you did `df['used_at'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))` then it would work but this is slow, you can use `to_datetime` to achieve the same result but this is vectorised:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['used_at'])
```

Comment: When I `infile = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("avito_trend.csv"), header=None, parse_dates=[2], names=['ID', 'address', 'used_at', 'active_seconds', 'pageviews'])` i get `ID address used_at active_seconds pageviews 0 avito_trend.csv NaN NaT NaN NaN Series([], Name: active_seconds, dtype: float64)`

Comment: Ignore the `io.StringIO` bit do this: `infile = pd.read_csv("avito_trend.csv", header=None, parse_dates=[2], names=['ID', 'address', 'used_at', 'active_seconds', 'pageviews'])`

Comment: If I print `infile = pd.read_csv("avito_trend.csv", header=None, parse_dates=[2], names=['ID', 'address', 'used_at', 'active_seconds', 'pageviews'])` I have a type error